# C# multiThreaded client-server

Tags: c#, client-server, serversocket

I am doing a multi-threaded server-client project. In my project server is receiving the connection request from client and provides a thread to handle read and send data. But while Reading data it's gives an exception at line 61.

```
networkStream.Read(bytesFrom, 0, (int)clientSocket.ReceiveBufferSize);
```

Exception is:

```
 >> System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Specified argument was out of the range
of valid values.
Parameter name: size
   at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 s
ize)
   at Server.handleClinet.doChat() in C:\Users\Mamun\documents\visual studio 201
0\Projects\Server\Server\Program.cs:line 62
```

I've uploaded my Project here :
http://www.mediafire.com/?z2z5moqn8zdl6pt

I'am using these code-references:
http://csharp.net-informations.com/communications/csharp-multi-threaded-server-socket.htm

http://csharp.net-informations.com/communications/csharp-multi-threaded-client-socket.htm

Please see my project and tell me what's wrong. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I guess It should be `networkStream.Read(bytesFrom, 0, bytesFrom.Length);`

Comment: yp.your guess was right. Thanks by the way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.networkstream.read.aspx) that error can happen if:

> The size parameter is less than 0.
>
> -or-
>
> The size parameter is greater than **the length of buffer minus the value of the offset** parameter.

I haven't seen your code, but would guess it's about the *2nd case*.
In the example from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.networkstream.read.aspx) they simply use the length of the buffer itself as the `size` value:

```
byte[] myReadBuffer = new byte[1024];
int numberOfBytesRead = 0;

do
{
  numberOfBytesRead = myNetworkStream.Read(myReadBuffer, 0, myReadBuffer.Length);
    
  //..
}
while(myNetworkStream.DataAvailable);
```

Comment: Yah !! Thanks. The problem was (int)clientSocket.ReceiveBufferSize.It should be bytesFrom.Length